# Not showing any validation error. i am trying to fetch error message when validation is getting wrong

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My form validation error stopped working, It was working yesterday, I must have done something wrong but can't seem to find it.

When I just click sign up without filling in any information it just redirects to admin_login.php which loads the view.

**admin_login.php** // controller file

```
<?php
//session_start();
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin_login extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('loginModel');   
}
   public function index()
   {
      $this->load->view('admin_view');
   }
   public function login()
   {
    // Load session library
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin', 'user_name', 'required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {

                 return redirect('admin_login');
                    //$this->load->view('admin_view');
                }
            else
            {       
                //echo "successful validation <br>";
                 $admin = $this->input->post('admin');
                 $password = $this->input->post('password');
                 $login_id = $this->loginModel->admin_login($admin, $password);
                         if($login_id)
                {
                  echo "valid admin_name and user <br>";
                  //$this->session->set_userdata('id', $login_id);


                  //return redirect('listing');
                 $this->load->view('listing');
                }
                else
                {
                  //$this->session->set_flashdata('flashError','invalid user_name/password');
                  redirect('admin_login');
                  echo "wrong admin_name or password";
                }                   
           }
        }
}
```

**admin_view.php** // view file

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>first tutoial</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to Admin Login</h1>
                   <!-- new line inserted -->
<?php  echo form_open('admin_login/login'); ?>
Admin User_Name: <input type="text" name="admin" class="text-denger"value=""  placeholder="admin name" >
<?php echo form_error("admin"); ?>
<br>
Admin Password: <input type="password" name="password"  value=""  placeholder="password" >
<?php echo form_error("password"); ?>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="">
</form> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this to

```
<?php  echo form_open('admin_login/login'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php  echo form_open('Admin_login/login'); ?>
```

your class name is *Admin_login* but you trying to open *admin_login* class

Comment: I am trying to open Admin_login page which contain login method so thats why i wrote form_open('admin_login/login'); which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

always use $this->load->view();
instead redirect(); function.
 redirect function does not show any validation error messages.